# What's the best way to connect a OracleDB and SQLite (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, oracle, sqlite, express, node-oracledb

I've started recently with a small project and I admit that I'm new to node.js, oracleDB and sqlite and all this technologies used in here.

I have a oracleDB connection to a database where I can fetch data from tables (which is actually working properly), altough I also have a SQlite database where I want to temporarilly get the information that I get from the oracleDB.

My big question is, what's the best approach?
I mean, should I create 2 different connections in 2 separate .js files or should  I create one connection inside other and try to make it work?

Thanks for the help already.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

> should I create 2 different connections in 2 separate .js files

Yes.

> should I create one connection inside other and try to make it work?

I don't see how you can possible do that since they're different database engines and require different Node packages/drivers.

Comment: Now that I'm reading what I've wrote, It makes sense that I would gone with the first option.
I've probably explained myself in a wrong way.
What I've tried to say is if I can interact with other connection, like performing a .post with a connection SQLite connection inside a .get of a oracledb.

I'm not sure if this is entirelly good ideia, because it might not be able to get all the info before running the post :)
Thanks in advance..